# unable to access Chrome Setup exe

Tags: resources, persistence

Unable to access Chrome Setup exe due to lack of setting resources to do this.  I tried too often and am stuck.  Need help.

Selected to download Chrome when signing in to my google account.  I expected to be guided to the correct next steps.  I selected to open file & got no next step.